# How to check if Anonymous Caller ID is enabled?

Tags: java, android, phone-call

In my app I want to allow users to call a number by pressing a button (using Intent.ACTION_CALL) only if Anonymous Caller ID is disabled. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this check, please?

Comment: this is actually a good question (at least in my opinion) I hope people reading this will not mark it as too broad and I hope you find an answer for it